# Update an instance variable in BPS

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process

Using WSO2 BPS 3.6.0 - is there a (standard) way to update an instance variable in an already running instance?

The reason behind is - the client passes incorrect data at the process initialization, the client may fix its data, but the process instance remembers the wrong values.

I believe I may still update a data in the database, but I wouldn't like to see process admins messing with the database

Edit:
I am working with the BPEL engine and my idea is to update a variable not from a process design, but as a corrective action (admin console? api?)

Thank you for all ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the instance variables during process initialization based on client's request.

For your requirement, where the variables need to be retrieved for the request. You can do this by using the execution entity to read the data instead of the instance variables that were set during process initialization.

Refer example below :

```
 public class SampleTask implements JavaDelegate {

     public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
          String userId = execution.getVariable("userId");
         //perform your logic here
     }
 }
```

If you want to keep using the instance variables, I suggest you to change the instance variable during the process execution.

```
 public class SampleTask implements JavaDelegate {

     private String userId;

     public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
          String newUserId = execution.getVariable("userId");
          setUserId(newUserId);
         //perform your logic here
     }

     public void setUserId(String userId) {
          this.userId = userId;
     }

     public String getUserId() {
          return userId;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However - I am using the BPEL engine (not the Activiti) and my question is about a corrective action when the process is running and we find the entered data are not correct. Our best advice (to support the data updates) is to store the production data aside and reload before each operation, however it was not implemented that way